# This is an invalid xsi:type DetectedEntity in outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to detect a pattern when a message is read in an outlook mail (web and desktop), so I decided to add the `DetectedEntity` extension point but I keep getting the following error on the web and it is not also working  on desktop office 2016.

> This app can't be installed. The manifest file doesn't conform to the
> schema definition. This is an invalid xsi:type
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides:DetectedEntity'...
> This is an invalid xsi:type
> 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides:DetectedEntity'.

**MANIFEST**

```
  <!-- Message Read -->
  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
    <!-- Use the default tab of the ExtensionPoint or create your own with <CustomTab id="myTab"> -->
    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
      <!-- Up to 6 Groups added per Tab -->
      <Group id="msgComposeCmdGroup">
        <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
        <!-- Launch the add-in : task pane button -->
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
          <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
          <Supertip>
            <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
            <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
          </Supertip>
          <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
          </Icon>
          <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
            <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
          </Action>
        </Control>
        <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ButtonCommands to learn how to add more Controls: ExecuteFunction and Menu -->
      </Group>
    </OfficeTab>
  </ExtensionPoint>
  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="DetectedEntity">
    <Label resid="residLabelName"/>
    <!--If you opt to include RequestedHeight, it must be between 140px to 450px, inclusive.-->
    <!--<RequestedHeight>360</RequestedHeight>-->
    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasKnownEntity" EntityType="MeetingSuggestion" Highlight="all" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasKnownEntity" EntityType="Address" Highlight="none" />
    </Rule>
  </ExtensionPoint>

  <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
</DesktopFormFactor>
```

How do I fix the Issue> I need a way to implement this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DetectedEntities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/extensionpoint#detectedentity) is only supported from VersionOverrides V1_1, if you are using V1_0 this error will be thrown.

The containing VersionOverrides element must have xsi:type attribute value as VersionOverridesV1_1.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! I completely missed that. Got it to work using an official git sample but I'm glad I've seen the difference. Thanks.